# Changing color effect on scrolling with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Someone can help me to achieve a color changing effect in scrolling from transparent to white like in the text that appears on this site?http://antonandirene.com/

(in the begging it's transparent in scrolling it become white gradually)

I tried to write this:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){       
        var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function() { 
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 650) {

                $("#branding h1").css('color', 'white');
            } else {

                $("#branding h1").css('color', 'transparent');
            }
        });
    });
```

but of course it doesn't change gradually, anyone has an idea how to achieve that?

thanks.

Comment: Use your browser's Developer Tools and inspect the DOM on that site. See how it changes as you scroll. In other words, reverse engineer the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the css property `transition` in order to make a gradual change from one color to another.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you

```js
var tStart = 100 // Start transition 100px from top
  , tEnd = 500   // End at 500px
  , cStart = [250, 195, 56]  // Gold
  , cEnd = [179, 217, 112]   // Lime
  , cDiff = [cEnd[0] - cStart[0], cEnd[1] - cStart[1], cEnd[1] - cStart[0]];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var p = ($(this).scrollTop() - tStart) / (tEnd - tStart); // % of transition
        p = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, p)); // Clamp to [0, 1]
        var cBg = [Math.round(cStart[0] + cDiff[0] * p), Math.round(cStart[1] + cDiff[1] * p), Math.round(cStart[2] + cDiff[2] * p)];
        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + cBg.join(',') +')');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    height:2000px;
    background-color: rgb(250, 195, 56);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>Some text</body>
```

Comment: the problem that it's change  the color and I need to change the opacity in scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code also

```js
$(document).ready(function(){       
            var scroll_pos = 0;
            $(document).scroll(function() { 
                scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
                if(scroll_pos > 210) {
                    $("body").css('background-color', 'white');
                } else {
                    $("body").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                }
            });
        });
```